Invoke-WebRequest passing creds via command line
I'm currently facing an issue that's driving me insane. Here's the code i'm running, pretty basic stuff.
$credential = Get-Credential
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "{some internal work/office website}" -Credential $credential


When I run this from VSCode, I get a popup box that prompts for login details. I enter my creds like I would on the site and I get an error message.

"Invoke-WebRequest : Unauthorized This server could not verify that you are authorized to access the document requested. Either you supplied the wrong credentials (e.g., bad password), or your browser doesn't understand how to supply the
credentials required."

When my colleague runs this command from his machine, he is able to put the creds in the VSCode terminal window and it lets him in no issues. No popups.

I 100% guarantee that its not invalid creds, since I log into this page daily. I also tried my creds on his machine that allows creds in the terminal window and that works. I'm starting to think that my computer is at fault.
Would anyone know where I would start looking, in terms of troubleshooting?
Thanks

I have declared explicit credentials and that works.
I have to declare my username and password in the script, great for functionality but not security. Can anyone answer as to why I cannot get the prompt to work?

How are you running this from VS Code versus your colleague? You might need to add a terminal.integrated.profiles.windows property for powershell perhaps but I'm not sure if that controls if it will launch in the integrated terminal or not.

The only - unlikely - explanation I can think of - assuming no typos, including due to accidental caps lock, are involved - is that Get-Credential is not the original cmdlet and has been overridden. To rule that out, start it as Microsoft.PowerShell.Security\Get-Credential

Have you tried tracing http requests on your machine and your colleagues machines using a man-in-the-middle dev proxy like Fiddler to see if there are any obvious differences? Or compare the vscode request on your machine to the one the browser makes on your machine? Can the support team for the internal app check their app logs and give more details about why authorisation might be failing for your vscode request?

What is the output from these two (2) commands? Get-Command -Name Microsoft.PowerShell.Security\Get-Credential and Get-Command -Name Get-Credential

Try with and without adding the server/domain name to the user account: <domain or server>/username.
